# Subquery in DAO Java

Tags: java, sql, subquery, dao

I have a select that contains a subquery and I want to get the result of it in Java, but I have only worked with simple queries until now. So maybe you can give me some ideas on how to do this. I have mapped my two tables and right now I am working on the DAO to retrieve the result from my subquery.

This is the function in my DAO:

```
public List<Object> getAllEntries(){
        Query query = emJAGS.createNativeQuery("select  nr, responsible, (select count(*) from table1 where idNr = cnt and month <= '2016/09' and month >= '2011/01') CNT "
                + "from  table2 where  flag = 1 and (select count(*) from table1 where idNr = cnt and month <= '2016/09' and month >= '2011/01') > 0");
        }
```

I have no ideas how to proceed further to get the result from this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How these tables look? What's the foreign key that is linking them? What do you want to fetch from these two tables?

Comment: I want to fetch nr and responsible

Answer (score 1):

The objects in you list will actually be an Array of Objects relating to the types as returned by `nr`, `responsible` and `count`

If you create a POJO that relates to this format you can use this [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) instead

Comment: if I want to get the results from two tables can I make a DTO, that has the data I want to get from both tables